# Android Studio: creating activity from template leads to undesired formatting Manifest file

Tags: android, android-studio, formatting, android-manifest

I'm formatting my Android.manifest file with 1 empty line between components (e.g. activities):
And it works pretty with cmd+alt+L (Reformat code)
[image: Android.manifest before]

But when I'm creating new activity using "Empty activity" template, studio adds created activity to manifest and automatically format it, deleting all empty lines between activities:
[image: Android.manifest after]

Here is how I'm adding this activity:
[image: adding Empty Activity]

This is how my xml code style settings look like:
[image: Code style xml settings][image: Code style xml settings 2]

What can I do to prevent Android Studio from deleting lines between activities in manifest?

Comment: I doubt that you can control this. File a bug report, asking Google to adjust their new-activity wizard to honor your code formatting settings. Ideally, they would automatically apply your code formatting after they add the XML element.